# react typescript send dom constructor as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, composition

```
interface Props{
    element: new() => React.Component<{}, {}>;
}

class C extends React.PureComponent<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props<T>) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <this.props.element>
            {this.props.children}
        </this.props.element>;
    }
}

function foo(): JSX.Element {    
    return <C element={new tr/* What goes here?? */}/>;
}
```

I want `foo` to render a **tr dom element** but I am having trouble reference the tr constructor.

Comment: I think you want `HTMLTableRowElement`

Comment: @Joe what is the syntax for that getting the constructor for HTMLTableRowElement?

Answer (score 1):

Remember TypeScript is a superset of javascript. So you would create the tr element the same way.

```
return <C element={<HTMLTableRowElement>(document.createElement('tr'))}/>;
```

Comment: I get the error message `JSX element type 'HTMLTableRowElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.`